# Is it possible to modify the selection rect for an IKImageBrowserCell?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ikimagebrowserview, imagekit, ikimagebrowsercell

We are using a subclass of `IKImageBrowserView` that contains a subclass of `IKImageBrowserCell` as the cells

The problem we're facing is when an image has a tall aspect ratio:
[image]

That first item can **only** be selected when you `-mouseDown:` directly **on** the **skinny image**.
I want to make it so that the item will be selected if you click anywhere in the `imageContainerFrame`

In `IKImageBrowserView`, there is a method: `-indexOfItemAtPoint`.
This returns `NSNotFound` when I click within the cell container frame, but returns the correct index when I click on the skinny image.

I don't think I can override this method to return the appropriate index when the mouse goes down in the cell-- but from what it looks like, that is my only option.

Does anybody know of any ways I could tackle this?

Comment: Isn't it just the matter of overlaying images with transparent square ones after rescaling them?

Comment: I believe that would force me to modify the underlying image, because that's what the ImageBrowser uses to decide on the selection rects.  I do not appear have control over when the images are rescaled-- It looks like I provide the ImageBrowser with Images, then I can call `-indexOfItemAtPoint` to see if I have clicked on an image